# JQuery set rotation position before start animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suppose I could also (or better) word my question as **JQuery, how to rotate image from an initial position different than 0 degrees**.

I want to animate the rotation of an image from `-50deg` to `0deg`. Unfortunately, for some reason, JQuery set the initial position to `0deg` no matter what.

My function:

```
$("#card").css("opacity", 0).animate(
    {opacity: 1, left: 200, top: 400, deg: 0},
    {
        //start: function() {$(this).css("transform", "rotate(-50deg)");},
        step: function(go) {$(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + go + "deg)");},
        duration: 1000
    }
);
```

Notice the line commented. That was a futile attempt to set the initial position to the desired rotation degree `-50deg` so it could go from there to `0deg`.

It doesn't help either something like.

```
$("#card").css("opacity", 0).css("transform", "rotate(-50deg)").animate(
    {opacity: 1, left: 200, top: 400, deg: 0},
    {
        step: function(go) {$(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + go + "deg)");},
        duration: 1000
    }
);
```

`JQuery.animate` keeps setting the card's property `transform` to `rotation(0deg)`.

How can I avoid this?

---

UPDATE

Thank you to **The_Death_Raw** for creating this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UB2XR/2168/) to illustrate the issue.

Notice, when you click the **click** button, how the object get rotated back to `0deg` before start the animation. I don't want that to happen. I wan't the animation starts from the rotation that the object already have (in the fiddle: `30deg`).

Comment: When is it supposed to occur? On click?

Comment: Look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/UB2XR/23/

Comment: Also you need to make sure that the `#card` element is `block` or `inline-block` level element

Comment: @The_Death_Raw answer was correct.

Comment: @AlbertSamuel : ty bro

Comment: @The_Death_Raw I want to start rotation from the position of ``"#MyDiv1"``. I don't want to start the rotation from ``0deg`` but (in your example in fiddle) from ``30deg``.

Comment: @The_Death_Raw See your fiddle, click the button and check the issue I'm facing: http://jsfiddle.net/UB2XR/2168/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    DoRotate($("#MyDiv1"), 30); // selector, degres to rotate
    AnimateRotate($("#MyDiv2"), 0, 30, 2000); // selector, degres rotate from, degres rotate to, duration
    
    $("button").on("click", function() {
      AnimateRotate($("#MyDiv2"), 30, 0, 2000);
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        AnimateRotate($("#MyDiv2"), 0, 30, 2000); 
      }, 2000);
    });
});

function DoRotate(element, rotateTo) {
    $(element).css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + rotateTo + 'deg)'
    });
}

function AnimateRotate(element, rotateFrom, rotateTo, duration){
    $({deg: rotateFrom}).animate({deg: rotateTo}, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function(now){
            element.css({
                 transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.SomeDiv {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:25px 25px;
    display:inline-block
}
.SomeDiv img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyDiv1" class="SomeDiv">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/cf/cd/c5cfcde4118dbc6b1c807f879602b9aa.png" alt="">  
</div>
<div id="MyDiv2" class="SomeDiv">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/cf/cd/c5cfcde4118dbc6b1c807f879602b9aa.png" alt=""> 
</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: it seems you didn't understand my issue. See your fiddle, click the button and check the issue I'm facing: http://jsfiddle.net/UB2XR/2168/

Comment: Notice, when you click the button, that the object go back to a ``0deg`` rotation before starting the animation.

Comment: @Ditto : you want to object go back to 0deg but with animation when you click on button ?

Comment: As I stated in my question: I want to start the animation at the current object rotation, which in your fiddle is ``30deg``. Unfortunately, ``JQuery.animate`` is setting the object initial rotation to ``0deg`` before starting the animation. I want to prevent ``JQuery.animate`` to do so.

Comment: @Ditto I think it's better to set a data attribute and check it when you want to go back to rotate from